# How to gather a group of players in a foreign country?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, social, group-dynamics, finding-other-players

I am a person who has to relocate a lot due to employment reasons. I tried to build English-playing groups with little or no success. In some cases, I was able to gather only one person or two. Only once I was able to gather four people (DM wasn't me), but the d&d 4th edition rules were too daunting to learn and focus. Things broke down after the first session (in addition, it required too much commuting).

Clearly, it depends on the city, and the country (d&d is not equally famous and played everywhere) but after you descend the airplane stairs into a new foreign country, what would your strategy be in order to find interested people and start a campaign?

Comment: Perhaps if your group didn't have to migrate with you? http://at-will.omnivangelist.net/2009/10/the-waves-the-thing-running-a-dd-wave-game/

Comment: @Richard : I did some remote playing via skype (Wave wasn't available at that time) but I always felt a bit ignored due to lack of physical presence. I prefer sitting at the table for many reasons: 1) I focus. Having the computer available is a distraction 2) I like to physically interact with things and people during a game 3) Many of my ex-players are computer illiterate, and internet was not available where they usually played 4) I can use D&D for social networking in the new city.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is:

- Check http://nearbygamers.com/ or similar player finder sites
- Find the nearest friendly local games store and ask/advertise there
- There might be a club associated with a games store
- See if there are any similar-hobby groups (such as wargaming) nearby as there is a lot of crossover
- Play online

Comment: I like the nearbygamers site. I already subscribed. Let's see what happens.

Comment: Meetup.com is making it fairly easy for gamers to find groups in areas with a relatively large group of expats.

Answer (score 1):

I'd see if I could find people who were interested in gaming as an English as a Second Language technique. This is totally hypothetical, but I know a few language instructors who've used gaming as a way to teach/practice English, and it's worked out very well as part of a school activity -- so why not as an adult thing? Maybe look at local colleges and the like.

Second: hit up your local consulate/embassy. US and UK both, and hey, Australian. Lots of English speakers with a certain amount of time on their hands. If you happen to be in a country with a US military base nearby, that's gold. Lots of gamers in the military. I'm honestly not sure how to get in touch with them, but they're there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to find (google) rpg-oriented community websites run by locals and see whether they have English sections, forums, then proceed from there on. :)