# Website with free pathfinder locations

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have played pathfinder 3 times, and have really come to like it. However, the family that introduced me moved away, and now I am looking for free locations to play. I have looked on the Pathfinder society website, but have found only paid campaigns.

Is there a website that includes free one night games?

---

I am looking for free locations that have one-shots and mini campaigns.

---

I am looking for a **website** that lists all of the local places in my area that host **free** Pathfinder sessions. Looking up the websites of the individual hobby shops takes too much time, plus I am not 100% sure if I have all the games then (libraries that host these events would be missed for example).

Comment: @BESW I am looking for locations. If there is a website that lists them that would be ideal... I am trying to avoid asking for areas near my locations because I don't want to be flagged as "too localized"

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4834/4398) help you, or do you feel that answers to that question *could* help you? If so, that's awesome! If not, then edit your question to show us how it's asking something distinctly different from that one, so we can be helpful to your particular issue.

Comment: You're looking at the list of PFS events here http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/events and they're all paid?  Are you sure? I suspect you're misinterpreting the links to the product page of scenarios they're running as being an event charge.  PFS events are usually free; some stores do charge a small fee for the space or the GM for buying the scenario, but that's a) unusual and b) usually $5 or less. Save your Coke money.  Or go find a real gaming group per the link BESW links.