# How do I get my BEM game up and running?

Tags: play-by-post

We (Bob & John) have spent the last 10+ years writing, polishing and testing a multiplayer game we are calling *ANTIQUITY*. We feel like it is finally ready to fly, so how do we get this off the ground? We are looking for about 150-ish players per game and are willing to open as many games as needed. We won't burden anybody with details of *ANTIQUITY* at this time, but would be happy to forward relevant game materials as requested. BTW, we both have decades of experience playing PBP and PBEM games; we just want to try our hand at running one.

Comment: Welcome Bob (and John). We don't do game recruiting here (take the [tour] to understand why) but take a look at [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37853/where-can-i-advertise-for-players-for-my-play-by-post-game) for places where your recuitment might work.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As the other commenters have stated, RPG.SE is a Q&A site; this isn't the place to recruit players for playtesting, though the linked question might provide some help in figuring out where/how to find players. [Once you have enough reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), you can also talk in [chat].

Comment: We might be able to field this question if it were revised to focus solely on “how to launch a PBEM campaign”. We’re not a platform for launching or recruiting, but problem-solving is in our remit.