# How to find a D&D group when you are around 12

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, finding-other-players

I am around 12 and I want to play D&D but I have no group. I can't find anyone in school and i need other ways. So if you can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you looked at http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232/23970? If so, it'd be nice to know what the answers to that question lack in your case. Also, (a) what country, (b) how mobile are you, (c) how populated is your easily-reachable area? (City, large town, rural?)

Comment: Do you care what edition of D&D?

Comment: Marking this as duplicate seems a poor idea.  The original question and answer is obviously aimed at adults.