# With Friends or Group D&D

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Hi so I recently played a campaign with my friends and I have to say I've had a real blast. So much so that I kind of want to make it a weekly thing. But they don't really want to play D&D very much. I live in a huge city and I know there's several clubs around here that play D&D but I don't want to go in and have it be super serious. I was wondering what are the key differences between playing in a formal d&d club versus playing with an informal group of friends? Also what seem to be the most common types of rules or restrictions in these clubs?

Comment: Related: [Where can I find other RPG players?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players)

Comment: Hello Paws, welcome to the site. Check out the [tour] and [help]. RPG.SE is a Q&A site, and consequently isn't good at any sort of discussion, personal opinion and lists. Maybe you want to check out one of the many [forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) instead? I hope this is not off-putting to you, and if you have a question about the game itself, feel free to ask!

Comment: Hi Paws, and welcome! I made some edits to your question to try to make it fit our format better. If you disagree with the edits or I got something wrong, please feel free to make your own changes!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question's too broad to usefully answer. RPG clubs aren't homogeneous, and groups formed by groups of friends aren't homogeneous, so there's no general statements we can make about how the two differ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Paws! I'm new to D&D too. I was just like you a couple months ago, so let me share my personal experience.

> What are D&D clubs/organized groups?

Not sure how to answer this without just repeating back clubs/organized groups that play D&D. So rather than *what*, I'll tell you *where* I went to find them. I went to [Meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/), searched for local D&D groups and found a game store that held Adventure League nights. You just check in, say you'll be there, and then show up. Easy!

> What kinds of rules or restrictions are common in these clubs?

Not sure what's common, because I only went to this one game store, but depending on whether or not it's an Adventure League night or something else, the rules and restrictions might be tightly focused on RAW rules (rules as they are written in the source material) or perhaps not. If they aren't, the DM ought to let you know at the beginning so you know what to expect.

I don't know if these qualify as *rules* per se, but in my experience there is certainly an expectation of your preparedness when you come to the game. Here's a list of things to bring:

- a pencil
- a PHB
- a character sheet
- some dice

I put *pencil* at the top of the list because that was the only thing that everyone at the table had a (jokingly) strong reaction to when I said I only had a pen. I would say the other three might be optional (the game store had dice, extra character sheets, and even a figurine I could borrow), but if you want to make a good first impression, come prepared.

> What are the key differences between playing in a formal D&D club and playing in an informal group of friends?

Well, if it's an Adventure League night, you're not going to see anything homebrewed, and all the rules are going to be pretty strict to the book. Groups of friends may be more relaxed about that. Secondly, Adventure League was heavily encounter-driven. You don't really get a chance to roleplay. Or at least we couldn't at my DM's table, which is ultimately why I stopped going to that game shop. But I met a lot of people I gel with, so it's definitely worth going, checking it out, seeing what kind of game *you* like to play.

Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

Go find a club, and check out DnD.wizards.com and look for where adventurer league events are hosted. They are usually held weekly. Our group is huge and hosts 4 full tables of DMs and players and we are already looking for a 5th Dm.

You may discover you develop a whole nother group of friends.