# The best way to get into an online game?

Tags: new-players

I am a person that's wanted to get into DnD from the moment I've heard about it. There's no groups I know of in my area that play it, and my close by friends don't seem interested, wouldn't know how to play and are generally too busy for this.

I have tried to get into online games with online people, however two of the people I know to be DMS are too busy by this point, and the third has no faith in online play. ( We tried regardless and it failed spectacularly when he failed to show up for around five consecutive sessions.)

I really want to get into this, specifically to play online. I'm scared of trying to do this in person, and don't really think I have much ability to go anywhere. I would be very happy to give any edition a try, but I don't know how to find any group to actually join.

Comment: I have read that, it doesn't specifically help because I really do need this to be online somewhere.

Comment: [A related answer that includes an online factor](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/30254/22566)

Comment: That post does cover online play, so its answers should help!