# Can I use a Forgotten Realms Adventure League Character in an Eberron AL Game?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, dnd-adventurers-league, eberron

Getting reading for GenCon and I've got a Lvl 5 Lizardfolk Paladin that I'd like to use in a series of Eberron games at GenCon. Other than some cursory googling, I don't know much about Eberron besides that it's pulpy, steam-punk DnD. I've been looking for something different and this sounds right up my alley.

I wonder if this particular character is the best fit for the setting though. From what I've read, deities work differently in Eberron. Would there be any reason, thematically and/or rules-wise, that a GM wouldn't let me use this character?

Comment: You mention that the character involves the Forgotten Realms in your title, but you don’t describe what about them is from the Forgotten Realms in your question, and that makes this impossible to answer. Please add in more details about the character, especially what about them makes them a “Forgotten Realms” character, and then we can probably help you.

Comment: @KRyan It's how DDAL is structured - there are two campaigns, Forgotten Realms and Eberron. There's no ambiguity in calling a character "a Forgotten Realms character" if one is familiar with DDAL play.

Comment: @T.J.L. Your assumption is that the “Forgotten Realms character” is one that has seen play in the FR DDAL—which isn’t a given at all. We don’t know if that is what it means at all. There are many other things it might mean, which could affect the answer. And ultimately, given an ambiguous question, the solution is to get clarity: there is no harm done in waiting here. Rushing an answer only risks a confusing mess with no advantage for anyone.

Comment: @KRyan The title says "Forgotten Realms Adventure League Character". Where's the ambiguity?

Comment: @T.J.L. There are *so many things* that phrase could mean. Even *parsing* it is ambiguous—does “Forgotten Realms” modify “Adventure League,” referring to the league set in FR, or does it modify “character,” referring to something about the character itself as being from FR? Is this an existing character that has seen play in another DDAL, or is this a fresh character from scratch—and if the latter, what’s “FR” about it? And so on. And we have already invested vastly more effort into this argument than this situation deserves—I’m done. I voted, you voted, that should be the end of it.

Comment: @KRyan You're demonstrating a lack of subject matter knowledge regarding DDAL play. You should recuse yourself, not get defensive.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is unclear. It is a 5th level character - it can not be a character "from scratch" - it **must** have seen play. (You can not create a higher level character in AL - you must start at 1st level).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TLDR: **In your specific case**, Lizardfolk are from *Volo's Guide To Monsters*, a book that is not allowed in DDAL Eberron play, and it did not start the Eberron Campaign at level 1. It is not a legal character for *Oracle of War* Eberron DDAL play.

### They are entirely separate campaigns.

DDAL's Forgotten Realms campaign and DDAL's Eberron campaign have different character creation rules and different character advancement rules. They are incompatible.

#### Character Creation is Different

From the *Oracle of War Player's Guide v1.3* in the [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack://). The first line (emphasis added) makes it clear Eberron characters are campaign-specific; even characters from the previous Eberron campaign are incompatible with the current *Oracle of War* campaign.

> CHARACTER CREATION
>
> You’ll need **an Eberron character made specifically for the D&D Adventurers League Oracle of War campaign**. Characters from the Embers of the Last War campaign cannot be used, although they can be recreated starting at 1st level using the rules of the Oracle of War campaign. All Eberron characters begin at 1st level, unless you possess campaign documentation that states otherwise or further rules countermand this.
>
> STEP 1: CHOOSE A RACE AND CLASS
> Oracle of War characters can choose race and class options from the Player’s Handbook, Xanathar’s Guide to Everything, and the Eberron: Rising from the Last War campaign sourcebook only (unless you possess campaign documentation providing additional options).
>
> You may select the Variant Human Traits option from the Player’s Handbook.

The *AL Players Guide v9.2 - Forgotten Realms* in the same [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack://) has different rules.

> CHARACTER CREATION
>
> You’ll also need a character made for the D&D Adventurers League. All characters begin at 1st level.
>
> STEP 1: CHOOSE A RACE AND CLASS
> Forgotten Realms characters can choose race and class options from the Player’s Handbook and one other resource—a rule called “PHB+1.” Additional resources include the following products:

I won't bother going into detail on the PHB+1 rule, it's been [covered to death here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=PHB%2B1). While there is sufficient overlap in the range of permitted books for one to create a level 1 character that satisfies both sets of rules, the requirement to start at level 1 combined with the Eberron requirement to be created exclusively for the campaign makes the characters incompatible.

#### Advancement is Different

From the *Oracle of War Player's Guide v1.3* in the [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack://):

> CHARACTER ADVANCEMENT
>
> In the Oracle of War campaign, your character advances one level at the end of each adventure, unless it is a special event, for which level advancement is optional. Your DM tells you when you’ve gained a level, and when level advancement is optional.

In Eberron DDAL play, advancement is controlled by the content you play - if you play, you must advance when indicated. The exceptions are explicitly spelled out in the individual modules.

From the *AL Players Guide v9.2 - Forgotten Realms* in the same [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack://):

> CHARACTER ADVANCEMENT
>
> Your character gains a level upon completing an adventure. In hardcover adventure sessions, your DM will tell you when you’ve gained a level. Otherwise if, after four hours of play (or eight hours at tiers 2 – 4) in a hardcover adventure, your DM doesn’t tell you that you’ve gained a level, you gain a level. In this instance your character advances to the next level at the end of the session.
>
> If you’d like to continue playing at your current level, you can decline to gain a level, although it has an impact on other rewards that you receive.

In FR DDAL play, advancement is effectively player controlled. During a hardcover session, the DM can trigger advancement earlier than 8 hours of play (4 in tier 1), but they can't prevent<sup>1</sup> a character from advancing at the listed pace. The player, on the other hand, has the choice - a player could choose to have a character perpetually in a choose tier by simply ceasing advancement. Eventually they'll run out of money and downtime (the "impact on other rewards" mentioned above), but it's an option for a Forgotten Realms character.

<sup>1</sup><sub>They can ask and encourage not to, but their only real control is refusing to allow the character at the table.</sub>

Comment: Unless they *are* compatible. It’s theoretically possible to create a character obeying the respective rules of each, but OP hasn’t given us nearly enough information to make that determination.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov The advancement is different. I'm getting there. Working from a tablet.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Also, the OP has given us plenty of information - they've picked a non-Eberron race from a non-Eberron book. Even if the character were level 1, it would be incompatible with the Eberron campaign.

Comment: @T.J.L. Great answer! While I'm disappointed that I won't be able to play an Eberron setting, I'm thankful that you were able to provide some clarity.

Side question, anyone have any resources on where I could find Eberron adventure league games online?

Comment: @DickNixon Make a new character, try to start from the beginning. As I understand it, the Oracle modules are tied together better than the FR modules.

Comment: @T.J.L. That's the plan, man. Thanks again! Checking fantasy grounds & roll 20 to try and find some games.

Comment: @DickNixon https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83618/43856 - we have similar questions on how to find online groups, maybe you can ask your specific question as well.