# Non-native at English RPGs

Tags: world-of-darkness, online-roleplaying, online-resources, gurps

I'm one of those guys. I want to play with some foreign players (GURPS, WOD) via the web. Sorry for a bit opinions based question, but I need it in this way.

What are the potential problems? 
Where are the best chances for finding these games? 
More particularly, where non-native speakers not something too unaccustomed and where the game can't be easily ruined by a bad Skype-link(etc.) plus far from native listen comprehensive?

Comment: We don't really handle open-ended requests for ideas here, but questions that can be answered definitively. Have you tried a [forum](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)?

Comment: Although the Stack isn't really designed to help you *anticipate* problems, we're well equipped to help you solve a problem you're experiencing. So, since you haven't started playing yet, the questions we can help you with are about getting started: you may find the answers to [these questions](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=find+%5Bonline-roleplaying%5D+is%3Aquestion) useful in your search for games. If there's something more specific about your own search those questions don't cover, that's something you can ask the Stack for help with.

Comment: Also [related] [Where can I find other RPG players?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232)