# Is there Adventurers League play in Hong Kong?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

Does anyone play Adventurers League D&D in Hong Kong?
I would really like to play D&D 5e!

Comment: Please take the **[tour]** to learn how the site works. You can find the tour by clicking here: **»[tour]«**. Thank you!

Comment: Since the answer to this question is rather...ephemeral, and it shares some of the other negative traits that make shopping questions bad...this is probably not a good fit for the site.  Poking your head into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) may be worthwhile though.

Comment: Do you "just" want to play 5e, or do you specifically want to play Adventurers League? [Where can I find...?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232/23970) might help a lot with the first, but none with the second. Also, let me second Shalvenay's recommendation that you swing into [chat]--there're plenty of chat-regulars who might (a) have ideas for you, and (b) help you focus this question so that it becomes a more-useful resource for future readers.