# What Is the best way for a new player to get started?

Tags: new-players

I am new to the RPG world. How does one finds a group that is willing to work with new players? What's the best area to start in? Any advice would be great.

Comment: Heya, Thewarblingllama, you're new: welcome to the site and this amazing hobby! If you have a moment, take the [tour] to get a little more knowledge on how we're different from other Q&A and the traditional forum, plus a bronze badge to boot!

Comment: I've retracted my close vote because it's the wrong reason. This Q should be closed as duplicate to: [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1232/23064)

Comment: Thewarblingllama - the recruiting methods for an RPG vary wildly depending on which game you are running. We would need to know if you were running something like D&D, Pathfinder, GURPS, Traveller, Star Trek, or World of Darkness to best answer your question. If you wanted to get a Star Trek RPG group, you might go to a Star Trek club or convention - and that's totally different from visiting a college campus at night to get into a Vampire LARP.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, purchasing an intro box is a great way to get started. You'll get a good sense of general rules.

1. [Pathfinder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601253729)
2. [D&D](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786965592)

If you're outgoing, check your local area for a game shop. You may be able to find groups willing to play with beginners.

You can also use something like L4G on reddit to find groups.